# Live, shared hosted, ASP.NET MVC site migration to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, migration, azure

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC based website. Very typical: XHTML, CSS, jQuery, C#, LINQ2Sql. Web.config tells app where to connect for SQL database.

**Are typical websites like this easy to port to Windows Azure? What sort of headaches should I be ready for if I decided to do this?**

It's not necessary at this time, but I'm planning for when I need to get the site ready for scaling. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd be interested to know more about this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found these [two](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109030810/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/12/18/moving-your-asp.net-application-to-windows-azure.aspx) [links](https://web.archive.org/web/20210120202839/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/12/19/moving-your-asp.net-application-to-windows-azure-ndash-part-ii.aspx) that seem helpful for ASP.NET. Plus [two](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925233447/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/09/29/taking-your-northwind-database-to-sql-azure-and-binding-it.aspx) [more](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924103516/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/09/29/taking-your-northwind-database-to-sql-azure-and-binding-it-again.aspx) for SQL Azure.